# Dyadic (tensor) product of four vectors

Tags: vectors, tensor-products, tensors, tensor-rank

I am currently working on a subject, in which the dyadic product of two and four vectors result  the second rank and fourth rank tensors as follows:

$$  M =  a a$$
and
$$  \mathbb{M}  = a a a a$$
If $a$ is a 3D vector, the above tensors can be stored in a $3\times3$ and $9\times9$ matrix respectively.

1. How the dyadic product of four vectors is calculated? I could not find the mathematics behind that in the literature. Which kind of product it is?
2. I found in an article, in a relevant topic, if someone does not want to use the second formula, he can use a model called the quadratic closure, in which the fourth rank tensor equals the dyadic product of second rank tensor $M$ by itself (something like $(aa)(aa)$ ?) and it is exact only if vector $a$ has some specific properties. How can we analyze the error of the model? I mean, how can we elaborate on the error between $(aa)(aa)$ and $aaaa$?
3. Assume $a$ is an approximated vector and there is some error in that, i.e. $a-a_{exact}=\mathbf h$ and therefore $M$ has an error in itself. What is the difference between the error in $M$ and $\mathbb{M}$? How one can elaborate on that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to note that for a vector $\mathrm v$ the tensor product
$$\mathrm v\otimes \mathrm v$$
Is **not** a matrix, it is in fact a second order contravariant tensor. As to the product
$$\mathrm v \otimes \mathrm v\otimes \mathrm v\otimes \mathrm v$$
The tensor product is associative, so it doesn't matter where you put the parenthesis (this answers your second question). The result will be a fourth order contravariant tensor. To answer your first question (how is it calculated) if $\mathbf{S}, \mathbf T$ are $(p,q)$ and $(r,s)$ tensors respectively their tensor product is a $(p+r,q+s)$ tensor with components that follow a straightforward formula:

### $$\left( \mathbf{S\otimes  T}\right)^{i_1\dots i_{p+r}}{}_{j_1\dots j_{q+s}}=S^{i_1\dots i_p}{}_{j_1\dots j_q}~T^{i_{p+1}\dots i_{p+r}}{}_{j_{q+1}\dots j_{q+s}}$$

As to your third question, what happens if $\mathrm v$ has some error, i.e if $\mathrm v=\mathrm{u+h}$. Well, since the tensor product is distributive you can just expand:

$$\mathrm{v\otimes v}=(\mathrm{u+h})\otimes(\mathrm{u+h})=\mathrm{u\otimes u}+2\mathrm{u\otimes h}+\mathrm{h\otimes h}$$
So it is just $\mathrm{u\otimes u}$ "plus a bit", where the magnitude of that bit will grow with respect to $\mathrm h$ at a $O(\Vert \mathrm h\Vert^2)$ rate, where I am using the Frobenius norm for a general tensor

### $$\Vert\mathbf T\Vert^2=\sum_{ \begin{array}{l}
i_{1} ,... ,i_{p}\\
j_{1} ,... ,j_{q}
\end{array}} {\left|T^{i_1\dots i_p}{}_{j_1\dots j_q}\right|}^2$$

Similarly for the fourth order product the error grows at a $O(\Vert \mathrm h\Vert^4)$ rate.

Comment: Thanks.
- Am I get it correctly, that for the formula to compute the second rank tensor, $S$ and $T$ is the vector $a$ and their product according to your formula is the second rank tensor. For the fourth order formula, $S$ is $aa$ and $T$ is $aa$ and their product results a fourth rank tensor?   
- If so, and If it does not matter where to put parenthesis, so why using the quadratic closure is not always exact? I mean, why $M \otimes M$ does not necessarily equal  $aaaa$? If they are equal, why do we need the closures concept at all?

Comment: @tio What do you mean by "closure"?

Comment: In the context of orientation tensors, closures are used to approximate the fourth-order orientation tensor as a function of the second-order orientation tensor. [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/List-of-closures-for-fourth-order-fiber-orientation-tensor_tbl2_334245753) is the list of the closures. For example in quadratic closure, the fourth rank tensor equals the dyadic product of second rank tensor by itself. In some cases, this model can be exact.

Comment: @tio I think those papers are a bit beyond my scope. My answer consists only of concepts present in multilinear algebra. I have no knowledge of the content of those papers.

Comment: Thanks anyway, just to be sure if I got your formula correctly:
For calculating the fourth order tensor, we compute $S$ as $v\otimes v$ and $T$ as $v\otimes v$ and then we use $S \otimes T$?

Comment: @tio Yes, that's right.